# How to change the length of the number after floating point

Tags: javascript

So, I have an object.

```
var position = {
  x: 1,
  y: 0
}
```

After few operations x or y can become something like 0.3700000000000001. However, I need it to be 0.37. I tried:

```
position[x].toFixed(2)
```

What is the right way to get get rid of 00000000000001 ?

Comment: What is problem using `toFixed()`?

Comment: You maybe need to do **position[x]=position[x].toFixed(2)**

Comment: I think that you can find an answer in this question which is very similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary In aswer given by [A Kunin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1736537/a-kunin ) you will find possible options and some cases when vaules can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem except using the string key or *dot* notation:

```js
var position = {
  x: 0.3700000000000001,
  y: 0
}
position.x = +position.x.toFixed(2); // + converts the resulted string to number
console.log(position.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

`position[x]` will get property of the position object which will be equal to value **variable x**. You should use `position.x`.

And you also need to change the value of `position.x` because `position.x.toFixed(2)` will not change the value.

```
position.x = position.x.toFixed(2)
```

`toFixed()` returns a `string`. You should convert it to float again using `+`.

```js
console.log(+(0.3700000000000001). toFixed(2))
```

Comment: This don't work, because `(+(0.3700000000000001). toFixed(2))` is `"0.369999999999999996"` and not `0.37`; `(+(0.3700000000000001). toFixed(2)).toPrecision(18)`shows it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a number, there is no way to drop `00000000000001` to get `0.37` exactly. Like for other languages (most hardware supports IEEE 754), the number `0.37` does not exists. If scanning `0.37` it is rounded to the nearest possible number: `0.37.toPrecision(18)` shows `"0.369999999999999996"`.

Because of this, `toFixed()` returns a string and not a number. So it is nonsense to use `toFixed()` and convert the result back to a float.

The easiest solution is to live with these *unexact* values and use `toFixed()` for output only (that is the idea of `toFixed()`).

Another solution for e.g. money is, to store all values as cent/penny and divide the values by 100 only on output: `($cent/100).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the value but you are not storing it, so the original vulea is not changed. You need to do:

```
var position = {
  x: 1,
  y: 0
}

position.x=position.x.toFixed(2)
```